# How to style text of Label vertically in GWT?

Tags: css, gwt

Ok, for `<g:Label />`, we can style its text as following:

```
.myText{
     text-align:center;
}
```

or `text-align:left;` or `text-align:right;`

That's it. There is no text-valign style.

So my question is how to valign text of Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All HTML elements align to the top of their parent element by default. You don't need to do anything for this to happen.

Comment: that's right, but it still have a little bit gap between the text & the top of the container.

Comment: This gap depends on the text/font, and it may be different in different browsers (or even different operating systems).

Comment: exactly right, in IE the gap is a bit smaller than in Chrome, but that is not a too big issue cos i set the line-height of the label to be shorter than the height of the container then it is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Read here about [CSS vertical-align Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) to understand about `vertical-align` property.

Its more about `CSS` styling there is nothing related to `GWT`.

Find [sample code here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_vertical-align&preval=baseline).